# How to avoid horizontal chart skip labels?

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using charts(3.0.2) library. I want to show all the data with their yAxis labels. currently, it skips one label, how can we avoid this?

here is a screenshot of current UI.
In this Screen, it is showing AHMEDABAD, CHENNAI, HYDERABAD.
But the original sequence is AHMEDABAD, BANGLORE, CHENNAI, DELHI, HYDERABAD(it skips BANGLORE, DELHI). It shows after zoom all the labels.
is it possible to show all the label at the first time without skip label?

[image]